Linux Mint group permissions don't work
I have users that are members of group mygroup, and I created a directory newfiles, then did the following:
$ chgrp mygroup newfiles
$ chmod 770 newfiles

I then used a different user who is a member of group mygroup to create a file or directory in newfiles, but get permission denied.  If I use the GUI "Files" interface in Linux Mint, I can successfully create a new subdirectory directory, but from the command prompt I always get permission denied.  This works fine on other flavors of Linux, but does not seem to work on Mint.  Is there some unique incantation I need in Linux Mint in order to allow multiple users to be able to create directories and files under a particular subdirectory?

Hi and welcome! Was your new user able to get to newfiles (e.g., can that user read the content of that directory)?  If not, it may be a permission issue with some directory "above" newfiles.

Yes, the other user is able to read and even create new directories using the GUI interface, but not using the command line.  From the command line, the contents can be read, but creating files or directories results in "Permission denied".
